# How to order by count in Doctrine 2?

Tags: sql-order-by, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to group my entity by a field (year) and do a count of it.

Code:

```php
public function countYear()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('b.year, COUNT(b.id)')
        ->from('\My\Entity\Album', 'b')
        ->where('b.year IS NOT NULL')
        ->addOrderBy('sclr1', 'DESC')
        ->addGroupBy('b.year');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    die($query->getSQL());
    $result = $query->execute();
    //die(print_r($result));
    return $result;
}
```

I can't seem to say `COUNT(b.id) AS count` as it gives an error, and
I do not know what to use as the `addOrderby(???, 'DESC')` value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what is the error you get when using `COUNT(b.id) AS count`? it might be because `count` is a reserved word. try `COUNT(b.id) AS idCount`, or similar.

alternatively, try `$qb->addOrderby('COUNT(b.id)', 'DESC');`.

what is your database system (mysql, postgresql, ...)?

Comment: I don't think the database matters with DBAL? Anyway, got it working with: `$qb->select('b.year, COUNT(b.id) AS mycount')->from('\My\Entity\Album', 'b')->where('b.year IS NOT NULL')->orderBy('mycount', 'DESC')->groupBy('b.year');` Thanks for pointing out the keyword issue.

Comment: Your alternative method doesn't work. Also, if you want to reuse your results as a subquery - (eg. orderBy) adding COUNT to select doesn't work.

Answer (score 49):

There are many bugs and workarounds required to achieve order by expressions as of v2.3.0 or below:

1. The order by clause does not support expressions, but you can add a field with the expression to the select and order by it. So it's worth repeating that Tjorriemorrie's own solution actually works:

   ```
   $qb->select('b.year, COUNT(b.id) AS mycount')
      ->from('\My\Entity\Album', 'b')
      ->where('b.year IS NOT NULL')
      ->orderBy('mycount', 'DESC')
      ->groupBy('b.year');
   ```
2. Doctrine chokes on equality (e.g. `=`, `LIKE`, `IS NULL`) in the select expression. For those cases the only solution I have found is to use a subselect or self-join:

   ```
   $qb->select('b, (SELECT count(t.id) FROM \My\Entity\Album AS t '.
                   'WHERE t.id=b.id AND b.title LIKE :search) AS isTitleMatch')
      ->from('\My\Entity\Album', 'b')
      ->where('b.title LIKE :search')
      ->andWhere('b.description LIKE :search')
      ->orderBy('isTitleMatch', 'DESC');
   ```
3. To suppress the additional field from the result, you can declare it `AS HIDDEN`. This way you can use it in the order by without having it in the result.

   ```
   $qb->select('b.year, COUNT(b.id) AS HIDDEN mycount')
      ->from('\My\Entity\Album', 'b')
      ->where('b.year IS NOT NULL')
      ->orderBy('mycount', 'DESC')
      ->groupBy('b.year');
   ```

Comment: +1 for HIDDEN. Fantastic tip. Doctrine kept messing my object mapping in the returned result.

Comment: Like the others said, `AS HIDDEN` was very helpful to me today

Comment: Unfortunately HIDDEN will not work when used inside an IN subquery. Please refer to my example: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/aa6a0ea06d7b5d4f0b04

Answer (score 3):

If you want your Repository method to return an Entity you cannot use `->select()`, but you can use `->addSelect()` with a hidden select.

`$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(q.id) AS HIDDEN counter')
    ->orderBy('counter');
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();`

`$result` will be an entity class object.

Comment: The `HIDDEN` statement is very useful to request entity of a single class only :+1:

Comment: In addition if You are counting from related entity You have to do **join** and **group by**: `$qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('item')->join('item.features', 'feature')->addSelect('COUNT(feature.id) AS HIDDEN counter')->orderBy('counter', 'DESC');`

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code for ci 2 + doctrine 2

```
$where = " ";

$order_by = " ";
$row = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select a from company_group\models\Post a " 
            .$where." ".$order_by."")
            ->setMaxResults($data['limit'])
            ->setFirstResult($data['offset'])
            ->getResult();`
```