# Doctrine DQL Reserved Words as entity names

Tags: escaping, doctrine-orm, dql, reserved-words

**Using Doctrine 2.**

I have an entity called 'size' and I'm trying to form some DQL (using the QueryBuilder) to pull these entities from the database.

It looks like 'Size' is a reserved word
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#id3

I'm unable to find a way to escape the entity name (I've tried backticks and double quotes)

```
$dql = "SELECT product p join p.size size";
```

Executing the above results in:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 53: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | StateFieldPathExpression | AggregateExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | ScalarExpression, got 'size''
```

It looks like where the manual talks about escaping reserved words - it is referring to column and table names. Can anyone shed any light on this? Is it impossible to used reserved (in DQL) words as entity names?

Thanks

Comment: What does your annotation look like in your entity for the table name? I recall seeing something before about having to use double quotes there around the table name for reserved words.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000622/how-to-order-by-count-in-doctrine-2). Easiest was to just use a different word like psize.

Comment: @Jeremy Hicks My table name is not 'size' so I don't have that problem (my tables have a namespace in front of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an alias I was able to overcome this problem.

```
$dql = "SELECT p, sizealias FROM Product p JOIN p.size sizealias";
```

I am not using straight DQL, but using the queryBuilder instead, the above solution works there too.

```
$qb->select('p, sizealias')
   ->from('Product', 'p')
   ->join('p.size', 'sizealias');
```