# Doctrine 2: How to sort by count of an associated entity?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

If I have a company entity, with a one to many association to user entities, how can I get a list of company entities, sorted by the number of users?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to order by count in Doctrine 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000622/how-to-order-by-count-in-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution but it is maybe not the best way:

```
SELECT 
    c, COUNT(u.id) as num_users
FROM
    Acme\Model\Company c
    LEFT JOIN c.users u
GROUP BY
    c.id
ORDER BY
    num_users DESC
```

After hydrating the results, you will get an array like:

```
array(
    array(
        0 => /* entity instance */,
        'num_users' => 123
    ),
    array(
        0 => /* entity instance */,
        'num_users' => 111
    ),
    // ...
 )
```

So you have to filter the results:

```
 return array_map(
     function ($result) { return $result[0]; },
     $results
 );
```

And that's it!

Maybe you can avoid the filtering part tweaking the hydration part.

Comment: If you write `c, COUNT(u.id) AS HIDDEN num_users` you get exactly what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13652479/842697

Comment: Indeed, the HIDDEN keyword was added since 2.2

Comment: In my case I had to add also a `->groupBy('c')` where c is was my first table selected