# Doctrine query with orderBy count

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have an Entity "Company" (linked to an "Account") which can have multiple "Tickets".

I want to get the five first companies with the most tickets

I've got this so far but it doesn't work :

```
public function getByMostTickets($idAccount) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where("c.account = ".$idAccount)
        ->orderBy("COUNT(c.tickets)", "DESC");

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Apparently, it doesn't like that I do the "COUNT" in the orderBy.

Comment: The cleanest way to do this would be to use a subquery for the count

Comment: Does your query work without the "COUNT" in the orderBy?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber it doesn't !

Comment: first you have to fix your query, by creating the right joins. Then have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000622/how-to-order-by-count-in-doctrine-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->join("c.tickets", "t")
    ->where("c.account = :account_id")
    ->setParameter("account_id", $idAccount)
    ->groupBy("c.id")
    ->orderBy("COUNT(t.id)", "DESC");
```

[EDITED]

sorry this should work... But dump the result to see what this returns...

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select("c", "COUNT(t.id) as countTickets")
    ->join("c.tickets", "t")
    ->where("c.account = :account_id")
    ->setParameter("account_id", $idAccount)
    ->groupBy("c.id")
    ->orderBy("countTickets", "DESC");
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the help :) Still same error, it doesn't want to COUNT to be in the orderBy I guess...

Comment: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 131: Error: Expected end of string, got '('