# Ordering Tag entites by related Articles count

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I want to fetch tags with their related articles. However the goal is to order them by count of related articles. How to achieve that using QueryBuilder and repositiry classes? I'm new to symfony and I've tried fetching tags by DQL but it was not fetching whole entities.

Tags and Articles are in @ManyToMany relation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shortDescription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Author", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $authors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->authors = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShortDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->shortDescription;
    }

    public function setShortDescription(string $shortDescription): self
    {
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Tag[]
     */
    public function getTags(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags[] = $tag;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Author[]
     */
    public function getAuthors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->authors;
    }

    public function addAuthor(Author $author): self
    {
        if (!$this->authors->contains($author)) {
            $this->authors[] = $author;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAuthor(Author $author): self
    {
        if ($this->authors->contains($author)) {
            $this->authors->removeElement($author);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Article", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Article[]
     */
    public function getArticles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }

    public function addArticle(Article $article): self
    {
        if (!$this->articles->contains($article)) {
            $this->articles[] = $article;
            $article->addTag($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeArticle(Article $article): self
    {
        if ($this->articles->contains($article)) {
            $this->articles->removeElement($article);
            $article->removeTag($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

My last method I've used in TagRepository:

```
public function findTagsByArticlesCount()
{
          return $this->createQueryBuilder('tag')
              ->leftJoin('tag.articles', 'article')
              ->orderBy('count(article.id)', 'DESC')
              ->getQuery()
          ->execute();
}
```

Comment: please show us your dql or querybuilder statements you've tried so far

Comment: @LBA last method added to post above

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000622/how-to-order-by-count-in-doctrine-2

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall a similar case I have 2 years ago, which I was able to resolve by having `HIDDEN` column:

```
public function findTagsByArticlesCount()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('tag')
        ->leftJoin('tag.articles', 'article')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(article.id) as HIDDEN cnt')
        ->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

However, I am currently not at my workstation to test this. Can you try it?

Hope it helps...

Comment: unfortunately not. I wonder is there any option to fech records as usual with findAll and then somehow count related articles and make proper for loop or something.
however i think it should by used by repository and QB.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing `groupBy` while counting tags in articles:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('tag')
    ->leftJoin('tag.articles', 'article')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(tag.id) AS tagcount')
    ->groupBy('tag.id')
    ->orderBy('tagcount', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Note: while joining `Articles` you will receive `number of tags * number of articles` records that you need to group by tag to count number of tags in related articles.

Note 2: I would prefer to use `innerJoin` instead of `leftJoin` not choose tags without related articles.