# API Platform : Order on count

Tags: api-platform.com

In my "Parent" entity, I have a OneToMany "Child" property.
I want to order on the number of "child". Any recommend way to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

My requirements were a little bit more specific. In the admin I had to **always** order the resource by count products.
Just in case someone else has this problem:

1. First we need to create a custom filter.
2. Next apply it to the collection.

The custom filter looks like:

```
namespace App\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Common\Filter\SearchFilterInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractContextAwareFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Type;

final class ProductsCountFilter extends AbstractContextAwareFilter implements SearchFilterInterface
{
    protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        if ($property === 'order') {
            $queryBuilder
                ->leftJoin(Product::class, "p", "WITH", "p.advertiser = o.id")
                ->groupBy('o.id')
                ->orderBy("COUNT(p.advertiser)", "DESC");
        }
    }

    // This function is only used to hook in documentation generators (supported by Swagger and Hydra)
    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        if (!$this->properties) {
            return [];
        }

        $description = [];
        foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
            $description["ProductsCount_$property"] = [
                'property' => $property,
                'type' => Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_STRING,
                'required' => false,
                'swagger' => [
                    'description' => 'Count by number of products.',
                    'name' => 'Products Filter',
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $description;
    }
}
```

And now we have to apply it to the collection for the GET method:

```
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:advertiser']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write:advertiser']],
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'filters' => [ProductsCountFilter::class]
        ]
    ],
)]
```

Research:
You can read more about filters here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/

Answer (score 0):

The response can be found there

[How to order by count in Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000622/how-to-order-by-count-in-doctrine-2)

code that worked for me

To suppress the additional field from the result, you can declare it AS HIDDEN. This way you can use it in the order by without having it in the result.

```
$qb->select('b.year, COUNT(b.id) AS HIDDEN mycount')
   ->from('\My\Entity\Album', 'b')
   ->where('b.year IS NOT NULL')
   ->orderBy('mycount', 'DESC')
   ->groupBy('b.year');
```